# Ionic 2 http undifined

Tags: ionic2

I am new on the ionic framework. Since then, I try to retrieve information in the comic with http.get and I do not succeed

Here is my code:

```
    //mon code dans le service d'authentification
getInfos() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            var headers = new Headers();
            this.loadUserInfos();
            console.log(this.AuthToken);
            headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +this.AuthToken);
            this.http.get('http://localhost/helloworld/authenticate/user', {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
                this.data = data;
                resolve(this.data);
            });
        })
    }


    //mon code dans la page home
    public viuser: any;

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public viauth: ViAuth) {
     this.loadinfo();
   }

   loadinfo() {
    this.viauth.getInfos()
      .then(data => {
      this.viuser = data;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not showing the entire code, but make sure you import the Http module like this:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
```

and inject it into your contructor:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public viauth: ViAuth, private http: Http) {
    this.loadinfo();
}
```